# How to click parent Form Navigation Tab from subform with vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a `submit` button inside the subform. When I clicked my `submit` button then this will click on of my Navigation TAB on the Main Form. The code must be executed inside the `submit` button event in VBA. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which exact event is triggered when you click 'submit' ?

Comment: `Submit` event executes an update query and then I need to reload the subform. That's why I want to click the `Main From Nav Tab' after executing the update query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is very unclear but if you want to run a code on Main Form than just create on it a public sub which would do your refresh:

```vb
Public Sub MyRefreshSub()
    ' refresh your main form here
End Sub
```

and on _Click event of the Submit button of subform call it like this:

```vb
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Me.Parent.MyRefreshSub
End Sub
```

or if you want just click the Tab:

```vb
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Me.Parent.TabCtl0_Click
End Sub
```

I hope I understood your question right.

Comment: Main Form button doesn't clicked

Comment: There is information in the subform, the submit button is updating that information. And since the form is open to updating, the field that is not supposed to be disabled after updating. Refresh or requery doesn't work. This is done only by clicking the Main Form tab. That's why I want to click on that button.